# shouldAutorotate is not locking the screen orientation

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I ma trying to lock screen orientation to only landscape orientation when a certain image is still visible, then when the image is hidden, unlock all orientations (targeting iOS 6):

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{


    if (self.splashImageView.hidden == NO) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;//gets called when image is visible
    }else{

        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;//gets called when image is hidden
    }

}
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
        [self shouldAutorotate];

}
```

As you may notice, `shouldAutorotate` is called properly but the screen is always supporting landscape orientation even when the image is still visible, is there something missing?

P.S: Please note I am trying to get that to work on a tabbar view controller (a `UIViewController` subclass).

Answer (score 0):

In your appdelegate you have those two methods.but do you have setting like in your project settings -> go to summary tab and see if orientation is set to only landscape or all.Just try to set those.

Comment: in project settings, NONE of the four orientations are selected.

Comment: yes, I can use those two methods in the app delegate, but i ma concerned by this view controller

Comment: select lanscape two orientation and portrait select first one not upside down.And in view controllers you need add these methods